# Testing KafkaStreams applications

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've set up a simple aggregation averaging values from multiple streams together and I'm trying to test it. I've been burning a lot of time and I can't seem to get the concepts straight in my head. My stream is below:

```
// Combine multiple streams together.
KStream<String, IndividualTick> tickerStream = 
priceIndexStreamBuilder.stream(exchangeTopics, Consumed.with(...));

// Group by a key & compute average per key
KStream<K, AveragedTick> avgTickerStream = tickStream.selectKey((key, 
value) -> value.getK())
            .groupByKey(...)
            .aggregate(AvgTick::new,
                    (key, value, aggregate) -> {
                        aggregate.addTick(value);
                        return aggregate;
                    },
                    Materialized.with(...))
            .toStream();

indexTickerStream.to(sinkTopic, Produced.with(...));
```

My test uses EmbeddedKafka, posts a bunch of records to topics, and sits on a blocked queue waiting for the records to arrive at `sinkTopic`.

I’m interested in how this aggregation changes over time, so I’m looking to assert that average on each output ticker. I may add some level of windowing, but I’ve tried to keep it simple for now.

When I run my test I get varying results. Assuming I have 10 input records into my topology:

- My aggregator gets called 10 times
- A breakpoint I put inside of my `AverageTick` serialiser gets called a varying number of times.
- I assert the values of the records in my tests.

I think this is because of the cache functionality defined in [KIP-63](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-63%3A+Unify+store+and+downstream+caching+in+streams) - The records are appearing very quickly to the processing node, and being coalesced/overwritten with the latest record. (I am not entirely sure though.)

I have unit tests passing with the `ProcessorTopologyTestDriver`, but I'm trying to write some acceptance tests for the service that holds this logic.

I've also tried playing with my `commit.interval.ms` configuration, as well as putting sleeps between publishes my input record, to varying degrees of (flaky) success.

- Do these kinds of tests even make sense?
- How can I assert correctness of this microservice against a real Kafka instance?

I feel I'm doing something conceptually wrong here - I just don't know what other approach to take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observation is correct. Caching makes testing hard because it introduces non-determinism.

To write a useful test you have two options:

- disable caching by setting cache size to zero (this way, all output records, including all intermediate are deterministic)
- only check the last result record per key (this last result must be always the same independent of caching for fixed input data)

Btw: in upcoming 1.1 Kafka adds a public test package and we plan to add more: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-247%3A+Add+public+test+utils+for+Kafka+Streams

Comment: I'll keep an eye on that KIP. Another way I considered was to send an input record, and wait until the output record is received before sending another.

Comment: That should work, too. But that is the same as disabling the cache.